# Are Paypal language options available in authorize.net paypal API?

Tags: paypal, authorize.net

We have a few clients who need it so their visitors can start off on the Paypal login page in Spanish by default. 
Paypal Express allows parameters to be passed into the setExpressCheckout URL, in order to set default locale and language.

Is there an equivalent of Paypal's LC or LOCALECODE parameters that can be set using the authorize.net Paypal functions, or a query string suffix that can be passed into the Paypal secure redirect URI, so that one can declare what language the Paypal login screen displays when Express checkout initiates?

Taken from this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/locale_codes/#localize-the-buyers-checkout-experience

> Locale Codes
>
> You can use any PayPal-supported language and locale to
>   localize PayPal checkout pages.
>
> Localize the buyer's checkout experience Pass a locale code to PayPal
>   to customize the locale of the buyer's checkout experience.
>
> PayPal payment buttons Merchants who use a PayPal payment button
>   (PayPal Payments Standard) can set the locale code using the lc
>   variable. To learn more about PayPal payment button HTML variables,
>   see HTML variables for displaying PayPal checkout pages.
>
> Express Checkout Merchants who use the Express Checkout
>   SetExpressCheckout ( NVP, SOAP ) or Callback ( NVP ) API operations
>   can set the locale code using the LocaleCode parameter.
>
> For an example, see changing the locale in the Express Checkout
>   integration guide.

And clicking the integration guide link:https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/#change-the-locale

> Change the locale
>
> You can change the locale of PayPal pages to match
>   the language on your website using either a 2-character country code
>   or a 5-character locale code from the supported codes listed on the
>   NVP/SOAP API locale codes page. To change the language displayed on
>   the PayPal pages, set the LOCALECODE parameter to one of the allowable
>   values in the SetExpressCheckout call.

Since authorize.net uses the Express Checkout API, is this option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass this as a parameter which is then passed through to Paypal. The field is called `paypalLc` and is nested under `createTransactionRequest` -> `transactionRequest` -> `payment` -> `payPal` -> `paypalLc`.

From [the manual](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#PayPal-express-checkout-authorization-and-capture):

> payPalLc
>
> Locale of pages displayed by PayPal during Express Checkout.
>
> Defaults to US.
>
> String.
>
> One of:
>
> - AU -- Australia
> - CAN -- Canada
> - DE -- Germany
> - ES -- Spain
> - FR -- France
> - GB -- United Kingdom
> - IT -- Italy
> - US -- United States

Here is a sample JSON request:

```
{
    "createTransactionRequest": {
        "merchantAuthentication": {
            "name": "",
            "transactionKey": ""
        },
        "transactionRequest": {
            "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
            "amount": "1.00",
            "payment": {
                "payPal": {
                    "successUrl": "https://my.server.com/success.html",
                    "cancelUrl": "https://my.server.com/cancel.html",
                    "paypalLc": "ES",
                    "paypalHdrImg": "",
                    "paypalPayflowcolor": "FFFF00"
                }
            },
            "lineItems": {
                "lineItem": {
                    "itemId": "item1",
                    "name": "golf balls",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "unitPrice": "1.00"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @john! All the documentation I was reading was in regards to the PHP SDK, where this is all undocumented. I guess I should have dived deeper into the API itself. 
I took a guess based on the JSON above, and called `$payPalType->setPaypalLc('ES');` and it worked perfectly.